# I am facing some issues with jquery-terminal while trying to build my own web terminal for my portfolio website

Tags: jquery-terminal

e.g. this.echo("Hospital Management System: Designed a full-fledged Hospital Management System Keeping in mind of all the necessary details and problems faced by the people. It was meticulously designed by keeping in mind of all the use cases involved. The system was implemented using HTML, Javascript, PHP, Mysql\n");

-The issue is that some of the words are broken in between by newline. So how to properly output the text without breaking the word
- The second issue is how to change the color of command in jquery-terminal

Comment: By default terminal is wrapping by end of the line, to wrap by word you need to use option, `this.echo("...", {keepWords: true})` see [docs for echo](https://terminal.jcubic.pl/api_reference.php#echo)

Comment: if you want to change the color, here is example using css variables https://codepen.io/jcubic/pen/oNXqJWY if you wan this to work in IE you need to use some polyfill, it would need help I can create a demo.

Comment: @jcubic Thanks a lot. And what a wonderful API you have made. Hats off to you!!!